# JS remove div with button after cloning

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem with removing div containing button. First I clone and add button, then change its class from 'add' to 'remove'. Then I try to remove div containing button with 'remove' but I can't access remove functions.

```
<div class="margin"></div>

<div class='new'>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success add"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var div = document.getElementById('new');
    $(".add").click(function(){
        clone = div.cloneNode(true);
        $(clone).insertAfter(".margin");


$("button.add:not(:last)).removeClass('add').addClass('remove');


    $(".remove").click(function(){
        console.log('inside')
        //$(this).parent('div').remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: would you please create a SO snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById('new')` ... ur element does not have an ID. Its class-name is 'new' but not its ID. Some corrections should make it work:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var div = document.getElementById('new');

    $(".add").click(function(){
      clone = div.cloneNode(true);
      $(clone).insertAfter(".margin");
      $("button.add:not(:last)").removeClass('add').addClass('remove');
      $(".remove").click(function(){
          console.log('inside')
          //$(this).parent('div').remove();
      });
   })
});
```

```css
.add {
  background: green;
}
.remove {
  background: red;
}
button {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="new">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success add">
      <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> new
    </button>
</div>
<div class="margin"></div>
```

**Edit:**

> Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Maybe like so:

```js
$('.add').on('click', function() {
  $(this).clone()
    .toggleClass('add remove')
    .on('click', function() {
      $(this).remove()
    })
    .prependTo('#new');
})
```

```css
.add {
  background: green;
}
.remove {
  background: red;
}
button {
  color: white;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="new">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success add">
        <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> new
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding events inside a click handler produces pretty bad results, you should be using `.on()`

Comment: I just followed the given code example and tried to change as little as possible to make it work ... while not trying to correct the approach as a whole

Comment: @Mischa Thank You :), that solve the problem. Is there a more elegant way to do this?